# PhoneGap Facebook Connect not calling back

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Mobile application that use facebook to login.
For this reason I used the [Official](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) plugin from phonegap.
The problem is that login method is not calling back in case the user cancelled the request where no error appear.

JS Code:

```
 ask_to_login: function() {
            try {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    alert("At response");
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_likes,user_friends'});
            } catch (e) {
                 console.log(e);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What does the plugin say it will do if you press cancel?

Comment: No error message: just an alert message saying :"Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login! Cancelled" that fire from facebook-js-sdk.js file.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem: Facebook login on Android using the official Phonegap facebook plugin was working perfectly. But after I did a mysterious change, I had the famous message : 
"Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login! Cancelled"
when trying to login.

The problem happens only with Facebook App installed. If it is not installed, you'll have a login popup and it works.

After a day of search I figured out what was the problem: I have recently added singleInstance launchMode in config.xml:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
</gap:config-file>
```

I removed this section and rebuilt the package : All is working again.

I wished to still have the singleInstance active though...

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, But i am using cordova and not phonegap build

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml file then, does it contain a similiar line : <activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" />

Comment: in fact Yeah, but for other plugin:     <activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ReceiverActivity" />

Comment: Removing localnotification activity launchMode attribute don't fix the problem? I know that you should keep it but just for the sake of testing...

Comment: @Moussawi7 and Houssem BDIOUI: I facing the same issue, i have correct hash key and tried by removing  android:launchMode="singleInstance", but this does not works.